# How to plot the probability density function graph for multiple data set in 1 graph?

Tags: r

[image]

I have generated 100 samples for Poisson Distribution with sample size `n = 100`, `lambda = 3`. Now I'm trying to plot the probability density function graph for all 100 samples in the same graph.

```
set.seed(124)


Sample100 <- replicate(100, matrix(data=rpois(100, lambda = 3),ncol = 1), simplify = TRUE)

View(Sample100)

colMeans(Sample100)
apply(Sample100, 2, var)

plot(density(Sample100),xlab = "y", ylab = "P(Y)",main = "Probability density function for 100 sample" )
```

What I get from the code is that it just providing me 1 line supposing I will get 100 lines in the graph because I'm having 100 sets of data

Answer (score 1):

if you are familiar with ggplot you can do the following

```
set.seed(124)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
Sample100 <- replicate(100, matrix(data=rpois(100, lambda = 3),ncol = 1), simplify = TRUE)
Samplelong <- gather(as.data.frame(Sample100))

ggplot(Samplelong, aes(x = value)) +
       geom_density(aes(group = key)) +
       labs(x = "y", #labs function overides labels on the plot
            y = "P(y)",
            title = "Probability density function for 100 sample") +
       theme_classic() +   # This changes the theme to look similar to base r plot theme
       #theme function allows you to modify plot further, everyting from size
       # fonts, angles, axis.
       theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, #hjust - horizontal shift
                                       face = "bold")) + . # face - the print for plot.title is set to bold
       scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0))  + #for the continuous x axis, limit expansion to 0 on both ends
       scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) #for the continuous y axis, limit expansion to 0 on both ends
```

for Reference you were plotting the following it seems

```
ggplot(Samplelong, aes(x = value)) +
       geom_density() +
       labs(x = "y", y = "P(y)", title = "Probability density function for 100 sample") +
       theme_classic() +
       theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
       scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0))  +
       scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

if ggplot2 confuses you, just take you time with trying to make the graph pretty, for most purposes the following is fine.

```
 ggplot(Samplelong, aes(x = value)) +
   geom_density(aes(group = key)) +
   labs(x = "y", #labs function overides labels on the plot
        y = "P(y)",
        title = "Probability density function for 100 sample")
```

Comment: make sure you have the `tidyr` and `ggplot2` packages installed and loaded

Comment: Can I add the x and y label and title for the graph like what I have done in my original code?

Comment: Sure, see my edits. I included more functions to make the plot seem as close to the classic plot function as possible.
ggplot2 is a great package, it will take some time getting used to how to edit and modify the plots

Comment: start from  theme_classic() +
       theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
       scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0))  +
       scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))    What are you trying to do not really understand how the code work

Comment: ggplot works by "adding" different layers to the plot. I will add comments to explain what each line does to the plot.

Comment: Thank very much. I'm considering that by using ggplot, it allow me the modify everything in the graph so does it mean that I'm also able to change the x and y axis value? For example like x-axis = 2 per unit, so that it will show the x-axis value in graph as 2,4,6,8,10....

Comment: yes, again there is a lot of diversity, the argument you are looking for is `breaks = c(2,4,6,8,10)` which should be placed into the `scale_x_continuous()` function